# uart1 in stm32 isn't worked

Tags: c, arm, stm32, uart

i try to send data to pc through serial from black pill stm32f401RCT6 i configure the driver from the data sheet but it doesn't transfer any thing i need help i stuck in this driver for a week
i enable uart clock and port A clock and make alternate function i do all thing but it fail i disappointed
here is my driver

```
#ifndef UART_UART_DRIVER_H_
#define UART_UART_DRIVER_H_

#ifndef __HAL_UART_DRIVER_H
#define __HAL_UART_DRIVER_H

#include "stm32f4xx.h"
#include "RCC.h"
#include "GPIO_driver.h"
#include "STD_Types.h"
#include "LED_Confg.h"

#define USART1_TX_PIN PIN9
#define USART1_RX_PIN PIN10
#define USART2_TX_PIN PIN2
#define USART2_RX_PIN PIN3
#define USART6_TX_PIN PIN6
#define USART6_RX_PIN PIN7


/* states of members of structure */

#define Enable  1
#define Disable 0
/*Different USART and UART peripheral base addresses */
#define USART_1 USART1
#define USART_2 USART2
#define USART_6 USART6



/******************************************************************************/
/*                                                                            */
/*                                UART                                         */
/*                        Register Bit Defininitions                          */
/******************************************************************************/


/* Word Length*/
#define UART_8_BIT_Word  0x0
#define UART_9_BIT_Word  0x1

/* OverSampling*/
#define UART_OverSampling16 0
#define UART_OverSampling8  1


/*******************  Bit definition for USART_CR2 register  ********************/
#define USART_STOP_BITS_1                          (uint32_t)0
#define USART_STOP_BITS_HALF                       (uint32_t)1
#define USART_STOP_BITS_2                          (uint32_t)2
#define USART_STOP_BITS_1NHALF                     (uint32_t)3


/*Parity bits*/
#define UART_PARITY_NONE                                ((uint32_t)0x00000000)
#define UART_HWCONTROL_NONE                             ((uint32_t)0x00000000)

/*UART Modes*/
#define UART_Asynchrons  0x01
#define UART_Synchrons   0x02
#define UART_Half_Duplex 0x03
#define UART_LIN         0x04

#define USART_BAUD_9600                                 (uint32_t)9600
#define USART_BAUD_115200                               (uint32_t)115200
#define USART_BAUD_2000000                              (uint32_t)2000000

#define UNUSED(x) ((void)(x))


/******************************************************************************/
/*                                                                            */
/*                      Data Structures used by UART Driver                    */
/*                                                                            */
/******************************************************************************/




/**
  * @brief UART Init Structure definition
  */
typedef struct
{
    uint32_t BaudRate;                  /* This member configures the UART communication baud rate */

    uint32_t WordLength;                /* Specifies the number of data bits transmitted or received in a frame */

    uint32_t StopBits;                  /* Specifies the number of stop bits transmitted */

    uint32_t Parity;                    /* Specifies the parity mode. */

    uint32_t RXIE ;                      /* Enable Interrupt for RX    */

    uint32_t TXIE   ;                    /* Enable Interrupt for RX    */

    uint32_t Mode;                      /*  Specifies whether the Receive or Transmit mode is enabled or disabled */

    uint32_t OverSampling;              /*  Specifies whether the Over sampling 8 is enabled or disabled */

}uart_init_t;

/*Application callbacks typedef */
typedef void (TX_COMP_CB_t) (void *ptr);
typedef void (RX_COMP_CB_t) (void *ptr);

/**
  * @brief  UART handle Structure definition
  */
typedef struct
{
    USART_TypeDef                 *Instance;        /* UART registers base address        */

    uart_init_t                    Init;            /* UART communication parameters      */
}uart_handle_t;





/******************************************************************************/
/*                                                                            */
/*                      Driver exposed APIs                                   */
/*                                                                            */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
    * @brief  API to do UART Peripheral initialization
    * @param  *handle : pointer to the handle structure of the UART peripheral
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_init(uart_handle_t *handle);

/**
    * @brief  API to do UART data Transmission
    * @param  *uart_handle : pointer to the handle structure of the UART Peripheral
  * @param  *buffer : holds the pointer to the TX buffer
  * @param  len : len of the data to be TXed
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_tx(uart_handle_t *uart_handle,uint32_t data);


/**
    * @brief  API to do UART data Reception
    * @param  *handle : pointer to the handle structure of the UART peripheral
  * @param  *buffer : holds the pointer to the RX buffer
  * @param  len : len of the data to be RXed
    * @retval None
    */
uint16_t hal_uart_rx(uart_handle_t *uart_handle);

uint16_t hal_uart_rx_CallBack(uart_handle_t *uart_handle,ptr_function CallBack);




#endif



#endif /* UART_UART_DRIVER_H_ */
```

```
#include "UART_driver.h"


ptr_function RX_CallBacK = NULL;
/******************************************************************************/
/*                                                                            */
/*                      Helper functions                                      */
/*                                                                            */
/******************************************************************************/

/**
    * @brief  Enable the given USART peripheral
    * @param  *uartx : base address of the USART or UART peripheral
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_enable(USART_TypeDef *uartx)
{

    uartx->CR1 |= USART_CR1_UE_Msk ;
}

/**
    * @brief  Disable the given USART peripheral
    * @param  *uartx : base address of the USART or UART peripheral
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_disable(USART_TypeDef *uartx)
{
    uartx->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_UE_Msk;
}



/**
    * @brief  Configures the word length for data transmission and reception
    * @param  *uartx : base address of the USART or UART peripheral
  * @param  wl    : if wl=1, then word length = 1s,9bits,nstop
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_configure_word_length(USART_TypeDef *uartx, uint32_t wl)
{
    if(wl)
    {
        uartx->CR1 |= USART_CR1_M_Msk;
    }else
    {
       uartx->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_M_Msk;
    }

}

/**
    * @brief  Configures the number of stop bits
    * @param  *uartx : base address of the USART or UART peripheral
  * @param  nstop    : this value configures the stop bits
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_configure_stop_bits(USART_TypeDef *uartx, uint32_t nstop)
{
    uartx->CR2 |= nstop<< USART_CR2_STOP_Pos;
}
/**
    * @brief  Configures the over sampling rate of the USART peripheral
    * @param  *uartx : base address of the USART or UART peripheral
  * @param  over8     : if over8=1, then oversampling by 8 will be used , otherwise default Oversampling by 16
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_configure_over_sampling(USART_TypeDef *uartx, uint32_t over8)
{
    if(over8)
    {
        uartx->CR1 |= USART_CR1_OVER8_Msk;
    }
    else
    {
        uartx->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_OVER8_Msk ;
    }

}

/**
    * @brief  Program the given baudrate
    * @param  *uartx : base address of the USART or UART peripheral
  * @param  baud     : baudrate value to be programmed
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_set_baud_rate(USART_TypeDef *uartx, uint32_t baud,uint8_t overSampling8)
{
    uint32_t val;
    if (baud == USART_BAUD_9600)
    {
    //16MHZ
    if(overSampling8 == UART_OverSampling8){//overSampling 8
        val = 0xD03;
     }
     else if(overSampling8 == UART_OverSampling16){//overSampling 16
        val = 0x683;
     }
     // 8MHZ
     if(overSampling8 == UART_OverSampling8){//overSampling 8
        val = 0x681;
     }
     else if(overSampling8 == UART_OverSampling16){//overSampling 16
        val = 0x341;
     }
    }
    else if (baud == USART_BAUD_115200)
    {
        if(overSampling8 == UART_OverSampling8){//overSampling 8
         val = 0x85;
        }
        else if(overSampling8 == UART_OverSampling16){//overSampling 16
         val = 0x45;
        }

    }
    else
    {
        //nothing
    }
    uartx->BRR = val;

}

/**
    * @brief  Enable/Disable the TXE interrupt
    * @param  *uartx : base address of the USART or UART peripheral
  * @param  txe_en     : if txe_en =1, then enable the TXE interrupt
  * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_configure_txne_interrupt(USART_TypeDef *uartx, uint32_t txe_en)
{
    if(txe_en){
      uartx->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TXEIE_Msk ;
      if(uartx == USART_1)
              HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
      if(uartx == USART_2)
              HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
      if(uartx == USART_6)
              HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART6_IRQn);
    }
    else{
         uartx->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_TXEIE_Msk ;
    }
}

/**
    * @brief  Enable/Disable the RXNE interrupt
    * @param  *uartx : base address of the USART or UART peripheral
  * @param  rxne_en     : if rxne_en =1, then enable the RXNE interrupt
  * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_configure_rxne_interrupt(USART_TypeDef *uartx, uint32_t rxne_en)
{
    if(rxne_en){
        uartx->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RXNEIE_Msk ;
        if(uartx == USART_1)
          HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART1_IRQn);
        if(uartx == USART_2)
          HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART2_IRQn);
        if(uartx == USART_6)
          HAL_NVIC_EnableIRQ(USART6_IRQn);
    }
    else{
       uartx->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_RXNEIE_Msk ;
    }
}



/**
    * @brief  Enable/Disable the parity error interrupt
    * @param  *uartx : base address of the USART or UART peripheral
  * @param  pe_en     : if pe_en =1, then enable the Parity Error interrupt
  * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_configure_parity_error_interrupt(USART_TypeDef *uartx, uint32_t pe_en)
{
    if(pe_en)
        uartx->CR1 |=USART_CR1_PCE_Msk;
    else
        uartx->CR1 &= ~USART_CR1_PCE_Msk ;
}


/**
  * @brief  UART enable transmitter
  * @param  : pointer to a uart_handle_t structure that contains
  *                the configuration information for the specified UART module.
  * @retval None
  */
void hal_uart_transmitter_en(USART_TypeDef *uartx)
{
    uartx->CR1 |= USART_CR1_TE_Msk ;
}

void hal_uart_reciever_en(USART_TypeDef *uartx)
{
    uartx->CR1 |= USART_CR1_RE_Msk ;
}



void uart_gpio_init(USART_TypeDef *UARTn)
{
    gpio_pin_conf_t uart_pin_conf;

    if(UARTn == USART_2){

     /*enable the clock for the GPIO port A */
     RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
     RCC_USART2_CLK_ENABLE();

     /*configure the GPIO_PORT_A_PIN_2 as TX */
     uart_pin_conf.pin = USART2_TX_PIN;
     uart_pin_conf.mode = GPIO_PIN_ALT_FUN_MODE;
     uart_pin_conf.op_type = GPIO_PIN_OP_TYPE_PUSHPULL;
     uart_pin_conf.speed =  GPIO_PIN_SPEED_LOW;
     uart_pin_conf.pull  =  GPIO_PIN_NO_PULL_PUSH;
     hal_gpio_init(GPIOA ,&uart_pin_conf);
     hal_gpio_set_alt_function(GPIOA,USART2_TX_PIN,AF7_UART1_AND_UART2);


     /*configure the GPIO_PORT_A_PIN_3 as RX */
     uart_pin_conf.pin = USART2_RX_PIN;
     hal_gpio_init(GPIOA ,&uart_pin_conf);
     hal_gpio_set_alt_function(GPIOA,USART2_RX_PIN,AF7_UART1_AND_UART2);

    }
    else if(UARTn == USART_1){

         /*enable the clock for the GPIO port A  & UART1*/
         RCC_GPIOA_CLK_ENABLE();
         RCC_USART1_CLK_ENABLE();

         /*configure the GPIO_PORT_A_PIN_2 as TX */
         uart_pin_conf.pin = USART1_TX_PIN;
         uart_pin_conf.mode = GPIO_PIN_ALT_FUN_MODE;
         uart_pin_conf.op_type = GPIO_PIN_OP_TYPE_PUSHPULL;
         uart_pin_conf.speed =  GPIO_PIN_SPEED_HIGH;
         uart_pin_conf.pull  =  GPIO_PIN_NO_PULL_PUSH;
         hal_gpio_set_alt_function(GPIOA,USART1_TX_PIN,AF7_UART1_AND_UART2);
         hal_gpio_init(GPIOA,&uart_pin_conf);

         /*configure the GPIO_PORT_A_PIN_3 as RX */
         uart_pin_conf.pin = USART1_RX_PIN;
         hal_gpio_set_alt_function(GPIOA,USART1_RX_PIN,AF7_UART1_AND_UART2);
         hal_gpio_init(GPIOA,&uart_pin_conf);
    }
    else if(UARTn == USART_6){

             /*enable the clock for the GPIO port A */
             RCC_GPIOC_CLK_ENABLE();
             RCC_USART6_CLK_ENABLE();
             /*configure the GPIO_PORT_A_PIN_2 as TX */
             uart_pin_conf.pin = USART6_TX_PIN;
             uart_pin_conf.mode = GPIO_PIN_ALT_FUN_MODE;
             uart_pin_conf.op_type = GPIO_PIN_OP_TYPE_PUSHPULL;
             uart_pin_conf.speed =  GPIO_PIN_SPEED_HIGH;
             uart_pin_conf.pull  =  GPIO_PIN_NO_PULL_PUSH;
             hal_gpio_set_alt_function(GPIOA,USART6_TX_PIN,AF8_UART6);
             hal_gpio_init(GPIOC,&uart_pin_conf);

             /*configure the GPIO_PORT_A_PIN_3 as RX */
             uart_pin_conf.pin = USART6_RX_PIN;
             hal_gpio_set_alt_function(GPIOC,USART6_RX_PIN,AF8_UART6);
             hal_gpio_init(GPIOC,&uart_pin_conf);
    }
}


/******************************************************************************/
/*                                                                            */
/*                      Driver exposed APIs                                   */
/*                                                                            */
/******************************************************************************/


/**
    * @brief  API to do UART Peripheral initialization
    * @param  *handle : pointer to the handle structure of the UART peripheral
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_init(uart_handle_t *uart_handle)
{






        /*Configure PINS of UART as Alternate function */
        uart_gpio_init(uart_handle->Instance);
        /* Enable the UART peripheral */
                        hal_uart_enable(uart_handle->Instance);

                        /*enable transmitter*/
                        hal_uart_transmitter_en(uart_handle->Instance);

                        /*enable reciever */
                        hal_uart_reciever_en(uart_handle->Instance);


         /* Configure the Word length */
         hal_uart_configure_word_length(uart_handle->Instance,uart_handle->Init.WordLength);

    /*Configure the number of STOP bits */
    hal_uart_configure_stop_bits(uart_handle->Instance,uart_handle->Init.StopBits);

    /*Configure the oversampling rate for the receive block */
    hal_uart_configure_over_sampling(uart_handle->Instance,uart_handle->Init.OverSampling);

    /*Set the baud rate */
    hal_uart_set_baud_rate(uart_handle->Instance,uart_handle->Init.BaudRate,uart_handle->Init.OverSampling);


    hal_uart_configure_txne_interrupt(uart_handle->Instance,uart_handle->Init.TXIE);
    hal_uart_configure_rxne_interrupt(uart_handle->Instance,uart_handle->Init.RXIE);
}


/**
    * @brief  API to do UART data Transmission
    * @param  *uart_handle : pointer to the handle structure of the UART Peripheral
  * @param  *buffer : holds the pointer to the TX buffer
  * @param  len : len of the data to be TXed
    * @retval None
    */
void hal_uart_tx(uart_handle_t *uart_handle,uint32_t data)
{

    while(((uart_handle->Instance->SR)& 1<<7) ==0);
    uart_handle->Instance->DR = data;
    while(((uart_handle->Instance->SR)& 1<<6) == 0);
}


/**
    * @brief  API to do UART data Reception
    * @param  *handle : pointer to the handle structure of the UART peripheral
  * @param  *buffer : holds the pointer to the RX buffer
  * @param  len : len of the data to be RXed
    * @retval None
    */
uint16_t hal_uart_rx(uart_handle_t *uart_handle)
{
     uint16_t data;
     while(((uart_handle->Instance->SR)& 1<<USART_SR_RXNE_Pos ) == 0);
     LED_On(&Led1);
     Systick_msDelay(500);
     LED_Off(&Led1);
     Systick_msDelay(500);
     data = uart_handle->Instance->DR ;
     return data;
}

uint16_t hal_uart_rx_CallBack(uart_handle_t *uart_handle,ptr_function CallBack){
    RX_CallBacK = CallBack;
return 0;
}

void USART1_IRQHandler(){
    RX_CallBacK();
}

void USART2_IRQHandler(){
    RX_CallBacK();
}

void USART6_IRQHandler(){
    RX_CallBacK();
}
```

i try this driver but it doesn't worked

Comment: If you're using CubeIDE then you should maybe just use the HAL it provides, and configure the UART from there (CubeIDE). This is an awful lot of code to study that could have problems.

Comment: what do you see on the scope?

Comment: Do you have access to the debugger? Or can you otherwise verify that UART hardware was initiated correctly, all the bits are set in all the right places?